# How to rearrange rows of resultset data in java?

Tags: java, javabeans, resultset

```
        List userProcessedCountCol = new ArrayList();
                  while (iResultSet1.next()) {
                        afRealTimeIssuance afRealTimeIssuance = new afRealTimeIssuance();
                        Integer i = 0;

                        afRealTimeIssuance.setSub_channel(iResultSet1.getString(++i));
                        afRealTimeIssuance.setAgent_names(iResultSet1.getString(++i));
                        afRealTimeIssuance.setFtd(iResultSet1.getDouble(++i));
                        afRealTimeIssuance.setMtd(iResultSet1.getDouble(++i));
                        afRealTimeIssuance.setQtd(iResultSet1.getDouble(++i));

                        userProcessedCountCol.add(afRealTimeIssuance);
}
```

where afRealTimeIssuance is  `ActionForm`

Using the above snippet I get something like below output

```
1             A             100
2             B             200
3             C             300
4             D             400
```

But I want to rearrange the output as

```
2            B              200
4            D              400
3            C              300
1            A              100
```

In short I want to rearrange the rows as I want.How to arrange the resultset data based on one particular value.Please guide

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ResultSet cannot be rearranged manually (only with sql) . What you can rearrange is your data structure that you hold your Objects

You can use an ArrayList of your row Objects and insert each row in the **position** you would like.

Lets say in your example, in the while loop:

```
userProcessedCountCol.add(index, element);
```

Comment: Is the following way correct to define row object? ArrayList<Object[]> rows = new ArrayList<Object[]>();

Comment: yeap, perfectly fine, but i think you you really need is ArrayList<Object> rows = new ArrayList<Object>();

Answer (score 2):

you can act as at two levels here:

- Database level
- Java level

At the database level the only way to manipulate the order of results to be returned is using ''ORDER BY ASC/DESC'' in your sql query. Note, that you can't rely on any other way to get the ordered results from the database.

At the java level you can store your objects like this:
 - use a sortable collection. Make your action form comparable or implement a comparator that 
allows to sort elements as you wish.
Then your can use [This method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator%29) to get the ordered collection by your own criteria.

You can consider also using [TreeSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html) instead of ArrayList
This data structure will allow you to just add the data and given the comparator that you've defined in advance it will be always sorted. The addition has a logarithmic complexity though, so its up to you to decide.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Either use an `ORDER BY` clause in your SQL query, or `Collections.sort()` the `List` using a `Comparator<afRealTimeInssuance>`. The former is easier and places the load on the database, the latter more versatile as you can sort based on external information.

On a side note, you should name your classes using the [Java conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconvtoc-136057.html): `AFRealTimeInssuance` instead of `afRealTimeInssuance`.

Comment: I don't want it in any sequence i.e. ascending or desc.I want to arrange it as I want.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways of doing this. One you can modify the query to use ORDER BY clause to arrange the results. Second you can implement the Comparator interface and define your comparator classes and use Collection.sort(List list,Comparator c) to order the data.

Comment: SO is a cooperative site (see the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#etiquette)), there's no need to repeat exactly the same answer as mine one hour later... It just adds noise. You can comment on existing answers so they are improved, once you reach a reputation of 50.